# Load a parsed CSV into memory in Clojure

Tags: performance, file, csv, memory-management, clojure

I want to load a file into memory, parsed with clojure-csv, and not the file itself. My hope is to have the data structure accessible in memory for high performance, but avoid the additional memory usage of having the whole file `slurp`ed. Is there is a better way to do this than to serialize (via Nippy) the parsed data structure (vector of vectors) and reload it? Since the file is accessed multiple times, I do not want to incur the cost of lazily reading and parsing the file each time.

Comment: You could transform the file into some sort of matrix, mmap it and then access elements in the matrix on an as needed basis.

Comment: duplicate of [using clojure-csv.core to parse a huge csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645160/using-clojure-csv-core-to-parse-a-huge-csv-file)?