# Double reading large CSV file

Tags: parsing, csv, clojure

I have a large CSV that will not completely fit in memory, and I need to do a lot of work on it. I'm new to lazy sequences, don't know how to solve this. I'm trying to read the whole file into memory, then parse it, I know that's wrong.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Read the header row and do things based on that. It's used throughout the program.
2. Read all the rows and gather summary data on each column.
3. Use the summary data to transform the original data and write a new file.

Is there a way to read in the header row and use it constantly without leading to the "holding onto the head" issue with lazy sequences, keeping the whole thing in memory?

I found this related thread: [using clojure-csv.core to parse a huge csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645160/using-clojure-csv-core-to-parse-a-huge-csv-file)

Comment: Parse the file twice, line by line. On the first pass gather your summary information; on the second pass perform your transformations and write the results to a new file, line by line.

Comment: Would I define two different symbols with `let` or reuse the same one? Why does this avoid "holding onto the head"?

Comment: Please see if my revision to the sentence question, by asking for the possibility of a specific outcome, moves this post out of "primarily opinion-based."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure takes care of clearing local bindings, so once a binding is no longer going to be used, it will be nulled to make it elegible for GC. So your code could look something like:

```
 (defn gather-summary [file]
    (with-open  [rdr  (io/reader file)]
      (let [lines (csv/read-csv rdr)
            header (first lines)]
          (reduce (fn [so-far row]
                  (if header
                    (inc so-far)
                    (dec so-far)))
                0
                (rest lines))))

 (defn modify [summary file] 
   ;similar to gather
   )

 (defn process [file]
    (let [summary (gather-summary file)]
       (modify summary file)))
```

`header` doesn't hold the head because it just has the first element, which doesn't have any ref to the rest of the lines.

`lines` is not used after the `(rest lines)` fn call, so Clojure will clear it.

`reduce` works on a recursive fashion, so Clojure also takes of [not holding the head in that case](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/FLrtjyYJdRU)

Comment: Consider using the term `binding` instead of `var`, because a `var` is a specific type of data in Clojure, that is mutable, and almost always global.

Comment: So the key to this solution is to encapsulate the file reading inside of the function using the file? That way, when the function returns, it knows to release the underlying sequence? I have been declaring the file sequence in the same `let` scope and passing it to all the functions as an argument, but that seems like my major design flaw.